# Enabling Managed Updates for Elastic Beanstalk with terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to enable managed updates with terraform but i am getting the following error

```
Error: ConfigurationValidationException: Configuration validation exception: Invalid option specification (Namespace: 'aws:elasticbeanstalk:managedactions', OptionName: 'ManagedActionsEnabled'): You can't enable managed platform updates when your environment uses the service-linked role 'AWSServiceRoleForElasticBeanstalk'. Select a service role that has the 'AWSElasticBeanstalkManagedUpdatesCustomerRolePolicy' managed policy.
```

Terraform code:

```
resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment" "eb_env" {

  setting {
     namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:managedactions"
     name      = "ManagedActionsEnabled"
     value     = "True"
  }

  setting {
     namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:managedactions"
     name      = "ServiceRoleForManagedUpdates"
     value     = aws_iam_role.beanstalk_service.arn
  }

  setting {
     namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:managedactions"
     name      = "PreferredStartTime"
     value     = "Sat:04:00"
  }

  setting {
     namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:managedactions:platformupdate"
     name      = "UpdateLevel"
     value     = "patch"
  }
  

}


resource "aws_iam_instance_profile" "beanstalk_service" {
    name = "beanstalk-service-user"
    role = "${aws_iam_role.beanstalk_service.name}"
}

resource "aws_iam_instance_profile" "beanstalk_ec2" {
    name = "beanstalk-ec2-user"
    role = "${aws_iam_role.beanstalk_ec2.name}"
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "beanstalk_service" {
    name = "beanstalk-service"
    assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "elasticbeanstalk.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "sts:ExternalId": "elasticbeanstalk"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "beanstalk_ec2" {
    name = "aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role"
    assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_policy_attachment" "beanstalk_service_health" {
    name = "elastic-beanstalk-service-health"
    roles = ["${aws_iam_role.beanstalk_service.id}"]
    policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSElasticBeanstalkEnhancedHealth"
}

resource "aws_iam_policy_attachment" "beanstalk_ec2_worker" {
    name = "elastic-beanstalk-ec2-worker"
    roles = ["${aws_iam_role.beanstalk_ec2.id}"]
    policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSElasticBeanstalkWorkerTier"
}

resource "aws_iam_service_linked_role" "managedupdates_eb" {
  aws_service_name = "managedupdates.elasticbeanstalk.amazonaws.com"
}

resource "aws_iam_policy_attachment" "beanstalk_ec2_web" {
    name = "elastic-beanstalk-ec2-web"
    roles = ["${aws_iam_role.beanstalk_ec2.id}"]
    policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSElasticBeanstalkWebTier"
}

resource "aws_iam_policy_attachment" "beanstalk_ec2_container" {
    name = "elastic-beanstalk-ec2-container"
    roles = ["${aws_iam_role.beanstalk_ec2.id}"]
    policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSElasticBeanstalkMulticontainerDocker"
}

resource "aws_iam_policy_attachment" "beanstalk_service" {
    name = "elastic-beanstalk-service"
    roles = ["${aws_iam_role.beanstalk_service.id}"]
    policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSElasticBeanstalkManagedUpdatesCustomerRolePolicy"
}
```

I did attempt to create a linked service role but that is not the solution for the error above.

```
setting {
     namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:managedactions"
     name      = "ServiceRoleForManagedUpdates"
     value     = aws_iam_service_linked_role.managedupdates_eb.arn
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

I was missing the following settings

```
setting {
      namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment"
      name = "ServiceRole"
      value = aws_iam_role.beanstalk_service.id
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`AWSServiceRoleForElasticBeanstalkManagedUpdates` can be used as service role for managed updates. Elastic Beanstalk creates that role if missing: [ServiceRoleForManagedUpdates](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html#command-options-general-elasticbeanstalkmanagedactions)

```
setting {
  namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:managedactions"
  name      = "ServiceRoleForManagedUpdates"
  value     = "AWSServiceRoleForElasticBeanstalkManagedUpdates"
}
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/iam-servicerole.html#iam-servicerole-slr):

> If you enable managed platform updates for the environment and specify AWSServiceRoleForElasticBeanstalkManagedUpdates as the value for the ServiceRoleForManagedUpdates option of the aws:elasticbeanstalk:managedactions namespace, Elastic Beanstalk creates a managed-updates service-linked role for your account, if one doesn't already exist. Elastic Beanstalk uses the role to perform managed updates for the new environment.